# Using GetProcAddress and EasyHook to hook class methods and constructors

Tags: c++, hook, getprocaddress, easyhook

I've had plenty of success using [EasyHook](https://easyhook.codeplex.com/) to hook system API routines (in C++) out of libraries.  These libraries have always been flat and basically filled with globally callable routines.  Here is a small sample using [MessageBeep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) out of the User32.dll library (minus setup code):

```
HMODULE hUser32 = GetModuleHandle ( L"User32" );
FARPROC TrampolineMethod;  // This would have been set to my new replacement trampoline method.
TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE hHook = new HOOK_TRACE_INFO();
NTSTATUS status;

status = LhInstallHook(
            GetProcAddress(hUser32, "MessageBeep"),
            TrampolineMethod,
            (PVOID)0x12345678,
            hHook);
```

This is all works great.  The problem is, I now have a need to hook methods out of a class, not just a global function.  I don't really care about the object itself, I'm really more interested in examining the parameters of the method and that's it.  I don't know how to syntactically identify the routine in the function name parameter for GetProcAddress(), and I'm not even sure if GetProcAddress() supports it.  For example, I'd like to hook the [Pen::SetColor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method out of the gdiplus.dll library:

```
HMODULE hGDIPlus = GetModuleHandle ( L"Gdiplus" );
FARPROC TrampolineMethod;  // This would have been set to my new replacement trampoline method.
TRACED_HOOK_HANDLE hHook = new HOOK_TRACE_INFO();
NTSTATUS status;

status = LhInstallHook(
            GetProcAddress(hGDIPlus, "Pen.SetColor"),   // this is probably wrong or not possible here
            TrampolineMethod,
            (PVOID)0x12345678,
            hHook);
```

This doesn't work of course and I don't think the *GetProcAddress(hGDIPlus, "Pen.SetColor")* is correct.  How do I specify a member function of a class to GetProcAddress()?  Is this even possible?  Also, how would this look if I wanted to hook a constructor such as [Pen::Pen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

The Portable Executable (PE) format that Windows uses doesn't really supports exporting or importing objects or their methods, so that's not what GdiPlus (or any other DLL) uses internally. The object notation is probably an abstraction implemented in the import library for the DLL.

If you take a look at GdiPlus's export table with the Dependency Walker tool (Windows SDK), or similar, you will see

```
GdipGetPenColor
GdipSetPenColor
etc.
```

So it is basically no different than the legacy exports, like MessageBeep.

Comment: Interesting.  Doesn't exactly answer my question.  But it's potentially an alternate route to get the same results.  Thanks, I'll pursue this and report back if it works for me.

Comment: I say this utterly answers the question. The PE format does not really have knowledge of OOP abstraction, to hook any such object it would need to be a COM object wrapper around GDIPlus.dll. But, that wrapper will call the DLL export eventually so hooking there is just as well, unless you only want to hook a particular COM object's usage, and then that's a different question about a different DLL.

Comment: The OOP abstraction mentioned here seems to be merely C++ header syntactic sugar, so the actually reality is it compiles to calling the aforementioned Win32 DLL export directly, there is no COM object or external OOP abstraction at runtime.